# How to get android:title from IMenuItem in Xamarin C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, menu

I have added items to the toolbar menu programmatically. Now I want to access the item's title attribute. I know you can use **item.getTitle()** to get the title in Java, but how do would you get the title associated to that item in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the docs for [IMenuItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.imenuitem?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) you will see that it has a `TitleFormatted` property that maps to the Android `getTitle` method.

Generally Android `getPropertyName` methods are mapped to C# `PropertyName` properties in Xamarin.